# Is it possble to sort by installation date by default in Windows Apps & Features?

Tags: windows-10

In the Apps & Features settings, sorting by name, size, and installation date is allowed. Is it possible to sort by installation date by default?

Comment: I don’t know why this was downvoted. You can set for a bit (I said that) but not permanently ( I said that as well)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the **App & features** are sort by Name in Windows, you can choose the **Install date** option in **Sort by** menu.

Note that this date does not always reflect the actual original date of installation. In many cases this date will reflect the last time that an update was installed for that program.

If you want to view the most recently installed programs, please follow below steps

Step 1: Click the Windows button at the bottom-left of your screen.

Step 2: Click the Settings button at the bottom left of this menu. It’s the one that looks like a gear.

Step 3: Choose the Apps option on this menu.

Step 4: Click the dropdown menu to the right of Sort by, then choose the Install date option. Your list of programs should then reconfigure to display the most recently installed or updated app first.

Comment: This does not save the sorting option you choose. I want it to sort by installation date by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible because I distinctly remember spending a lot of time looking for how to do it on my last w10 install, and finally doing it. That or maybe my mind playing tricks on me. Too bad I'm too lazy to do it this time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1145762)

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not provide a built-in registry key that allows you to permanently sort the "Programs and Features" list by date.

So, its only possible to change the drop down or do it by PowerShell like so:

Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* | Select-Object DisplayName, InstallDate | Sort-Object InstallDate

This command retrieves information about installed programs from the Uninstall registry key, selects the display name and install date, and then sorts the results by the install date.